# Set up Ctrl-V in Ideavim

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

I use **ideavim** plugin, but I do not use any vim hotkey with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Recently, I found out a great multicursor analog is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in vim. But I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> as a paste command in Idea. Could I somehow reassign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to be visual block by typing something like **ff** .

I tried to create a map in .vimrc file:

```
:imap ff <C-v>
```

but it does not work.

Comment: <C-v> should be used in the Normal mode while you're mapping ff to it in the Insert mode.

Comment: You should do mapping like `nnoremap ff <c-v>`. Then `ff` will start new visual block

Comment: dlmeetei thanks a lot ! It works